# Reusing 2D array in VBA Excel?

Tags: arrays, vba, excel

New here, and new to VBA and programming in general.

I am trying to reuse multiple arrays (through a loop), but I assume I need to clear them out before I reuse them? I have tried searching through the questions, but I can't find a solution, or frankly can't understand the solutions if they work.

```
Dim WS As Worksheet

For Each WS In Worksheets
    If Right(WS.Name, 4) = "Data" Then Comp = Comp + 1
Next WS

Dim CompArray(10, 50) As Variant
Dim RatesArray(10, 1 To 50) As Variant
Dim IndexArray(10, 50) As Variant
Dim ShortIndexArray(10) As Long
Dim MRow, DRow, FRow, RRow, Col As Long
Dim LastCol, LastRow As Long

MRow = 4
LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row


Do Until MRow > LastRow

    '**** MY CODE ****

''''***!!!*** Trying to Clear the array and reuse with the same dimensions for each loop ***!!!***
' not working

''Erase CompArray, RatesArray, IndexArray, ShortIndexArray
''ReDim CompArray(10, 50)
''ReDim RatesArray(10, 1 To 50)
''ReDim IndexArray(10, 50)
''ReDim ShortIndexArray(10)

MRow = MRow + 6 + Comp
Loop




End Sub
```

so when I go to the next step of the main loop, the arrays that I want to use have the same information. I want to keep the same names and dimensions of the arrays, but just clear out the contents. It sounds simple to me, but I have no idea how to do this.

I tried erasing and redim-ing (that was a solution to a similar problem on here) but it didnt work, it actually was saying I was declaring the arrays twice.

I also tried dim-ing the arrays while already in the loop. That didn't work either.

Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks.

Comment: `ReDim` works.  Try it again.

Comment: @RBarryYoung Probably attempting to use the type in the statement, after it's already been declared. `ReDim CompArray(10, 50) As Variant` will fail. `ReDim CompArray(10, 50)` won't.

Comment: @Sam That's what I suspected too at first, but the code that's commented-out doesn't have that.  As far as I can tell, if the `ReDim`s were just uncommented, it should work.

Comment: ahh.. He needs to declare the arrays with no dimensions initially, or you get the `Array already dimensioned` error, when you try to `ReDim`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to reuse an array then you shouldn't specify the dimensions when you first declare it

```
Dim CompArray() As Variant
```

Then when you want to initialize it you use the keyword `Redim`

```
ReDim CompArray(10, 50)
```

If you redim your array again then you will loose any data already stored in it, unless you use the `Preserve` keyword

```
ReDim Preserve CompArray(10, 60)
```

And if you're redimensioning your array and preserving the content then you can only change the last dimension

so `ReDim Preserve CompArray(10, 80)` will work as you're changing the last element. `ReDim Preserve CompArray(100, 80)` will cause an error as you're attempting to change the first element and preserve the data.

`ReDim CompArray(100, 800)` will work fine, but you will lose all your currently stored data.

Comment: +1: Oh right!  I forgot that arrays could be dynamic ***or*** static in VBA and that you use the `Dim` to distinguish them.  (they're always dynamic in VB.net)

Comment: Wow! Thanks Sam and RBarryYoung. You guys are excellent. Solution works great.